# Adding value dynamically in buildout configuration

Tags: plone, buildout

I am looking for populating value, in zc.buildout configuration, by evaluating certain criteria. For example,

if fqdn endswith '.net'
then
     hostname = this_pkg_server
else
     hostname = that_pkg_server

I am looking to build site specific configuration. I can evaluate fqdn with macro but how to populate that value in configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest answer is to use the wonderful `mr.scripty`.

Page on PyPI:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.scripty

Untested example:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    hostname 

[hostname]
recipe=mr.scripty
pkg_server=
    ... import os
    ... if os.environ.get('HOSTNAME', '').endswith('.net'):
    ...     return 'this_pkg_server'
    ... return 'that_pkg_server'
```

You can then use across your buildout the returned value as `${hostname:pkg_server}`.

There is a more complex solution, i.e. writing your own buildout recipe.
It is not that easy, but the effort may not be worth the task.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this option. I was reading through manual and got conditional section. That too helped me for now. But for sure your solution is better one.

Comment: You are welcome :) And thanks to you because you pointed me to conditional sections, whose existence I did not know!